# What's the difference between MAC and "hash first, encrypt next"?

Tags: security, encryption, hash

MAC provides data integrity, authenticity by using hash function and encryption

But why don't we just hash a message and then encrypt it to achieve the same purpose?

E(H(m),m)

We first hash plaintext m and then we encrypt m along with the digest.

Does E(H(m),m) has the same functionality as MAC?Thanks.

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-24-encrypt-then-mac.html http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption

Comment: A MAC doesn't encrypt at all (though it's often used in tandem with encryption), maybe you're asking how a MAC differs from a hash function?